# Why are there some objects which are not visible in Object Manager in salesforce?

Tags: lightning-experience, sobject

There are some standard objects like *ContentDocumentLink, ContentDocument, ContentDocumentHistory*; why these aren't visible in object manager or schema builder even when you have admin privileges.

what setting decides which standard objects will be visible in Object Manger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, only objects that can be customized appear in Object Manager. An object is considered customizable if you can add custom fields to the object. Objects like Custom Document Link, while supporting automations (e.g. triggers), do not support customization, and therefore don't appear in the Object Manager.

Comment: N.B. as of V60, I don't think `ContentDocumentLink` is supported by record-triggered flows

Comment: @cropredy you are correct. I'm not sure there are any examples of non-customizable objects that support record-triggered flows at this time.

Comment: Counterexample: Only `SurveyInvitation` and `SurveySubject` are customizable but more `SurveyXXX` objects can be used in Record-triggered flows (or at least based on inspection of our org using SurveyResponse Pack license, not sure if this changes with Feedback Management licenses)